# Firebase autologin (first time login) workflow for c++ bindings

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanna get subj workflow for my program, but I don't want store users login/password pair in open way.
What I should use for realize that workflow in my app?
Any advises ? Thanks.

update:
What I have now, simple app, written in Qt/Qml and uses Firebase C++ api.

On Start I'n getting Firebase::App and Firebase::Auth succefully init.
After init Auth, I am register AuthStateListener Class with simple handler code:

```
void AuthManager::OnAuthStateChanged(firebase::auth::Auth *auth)
{

    if(auth->CurrentUser()){
        qDebug() << "get auth :" << auth->CurrentUser()->Email().c_str();
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "still not auth";
    }
}
```

After start app it writes to console second-branch log ("still not auth").
And none happens else.
Then, in gui I click to my signIn button and do `SignInWithEmailAndPassword` in button's handler.
After that I get new event in `OnAuthStateChanged`. Now I authorizated, but no autologin.
Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by updating to Firebase C++ SDK 2.1.0 (from 9dec 2016)

Comment: Did you find an answer to [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1tF4_KbWNhUJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/40897719/undefined-symbols-at-firebasevariant+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=dk&client=ubuntu)? I'm asking because I have a very similar output when trying to link against libanalytics.a

Comment: @Larpon, reorder you link libraries list. Some static libraries should link before or after some another. Play with order.

Comment: Yups that was it!

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase, you receive an access token after authentication, and Firebase manages the session for you. Thus, there's no need to store user login/password or the token either.

Instead, you can use [AddAuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/auth/auth#classfirebase_1_1auth_1_1_auth_1add18126b0c434561cb48c82354ce5b87) to detect when authentication state changes (e.g. when the user is signed in).

Note also that, should you need to pass the token to a server-side process for verification of identity, you can use the [Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/auth/user#classfirebase_1_1auth_1_1_user_1ac7d5574b4f7fd57fdf57050371419287) method for this, and the Firebase server/admin SDKs include a strategy to [verify ids tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: Sorry, I still dont understand. How firebase logins after program are closed ?

Comment: Why would you want to authenticate while the program is closed? That doesn't make any sense to me. What I said here is that it authenticates when the app is reopened.

Comment: No, it not.
Btw, it not for me. May be I do something wrong.
I created AuthStateListenet and it catched only one event,  and at that moment firebase still not auth. I check for auth->CurrentUser() == nullptr and get true.

Comment: After that, i logins in my programm and it(AuthStateListener) get event about succes auth...so..May be I should do something else?

Comment: Code it or it didn't happen : )  Happy to help, but I can't take any guesses without enough info to reproduce and verify the issue. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: any ideas on topic?